# Google Chrome Frame & Big Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, canvas

I need to connect Google Chrome Frame to my project. It based on Canvas, a lot of big elemements.
Everything is all right, GHF works correctly, buy...
When square of canvas is greater than 2<sup>16</sup> it doesn't works correctly. E.G. if size of canvas is 256x256 or 512x128 - it works, like in Chrome.
But if size is 257x256 or 515x128 - there are nothing on my canvas.

Checked in IE7 & IE8.

Here is my test code: http://theshock.github.com/trash/chrome-frame-fail.html

Here is result in IE8. U can see, that rectangles draws correctly in smaller canvases, but larger canvasesare clear:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a problem in Google Chrome in general, not just in Google Chrome Frame. Opening that page in my Windows XP VM with Chrome  24.0.1312.57 m leads to blank large canvases too.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Chrome 25.0.1364.160 resolved the problem for me both in Chrome Frame and Chrome standalone.

Comment: I'm on Chrome v 28.0.1500.63 m, and I also get this problem.
A canvas of size (4000, 1300) would display fine, but my canvas of size (4121, 1300) wouldn't display at all.  Yet the "getContext" function didn't return "null", so my JavaScript was under the impression that there was no issue.  (sigh.)   And in IE10, it'd display fine.